# Setting UILabel with multiple font color at drawatpoint

Tags: objective-c, uilabel

How to set the multiple font color in UIlabel drawatpoint.

I tried using below code to change the font attribute but I have no idea how to set a NSMutableAttributedString to this since it only accepts NSDictionary

```
[self.textColor setFill];
[self.text drawAtPoint:rect2.origin withAttributes:attrName];
```

We use this to set the attribute

```
NSMutableAttributedString *attrsString =  
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] 
initWithAttributedString:"String1/String2"];

// search for word occurrence
NSRange prange = [lbl.text rangeOfString:@"String1"];
NSRange lrange = [lbl.text rangeOfString:@"String2"];

if (prange.location != NSNotFound) {
     [attrsString addAttributes:attributeGreen range:prange];
     [attrsString addAttributes:attributeRed range:lrange];
}
lbl.attributedText = attrsString;
```

Originally we use this in the UILabel subclass - this subclass is used to resize the text.

```
[self.textColor setFill];
[self.text drawAtPoint:rect2.origin withFont:tmpfont];
```

I expect to have String1 in green font and String 2 in red font

Comment: Note that `drawAtPoint` can be used on `NSAttributedString`: [attrsString drawAtPoint:rect2.origin]` https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring/1529478-drawatpoint?language=objc With `drawAtPoint:` of `NSString`, the effects will be the same for the whole text.

Comment: @Larme well that did the trick. thanks I spent a day and a half trying to find the solution to this. beginner problems -___-

Answer (score 2):

Add a font attribute with font size.

```
NSString *string = @"String1/String2";

NSMutableAttributedString *attrsString =  
[[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] 
initWithAttributedString:@"String1/String2"];

// search for word occurrence
NSRange prange = [lbl.text rangeOfString:@"String1"];
NSRange lrange = [lbl.text rangeOfString:@"String2"];

//Setting font 
[attrString addAttribute:NSFontAttributeName value:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:16] range:NSMakeRange(0, string.length)];

if (prange.location != NSNotFound) {
 [attrsString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor greenColor] range:prange];
}
if (lrange.location != NSNotFound) {
 [attrsString addAttribute: NSForegroundColorAttributeName value: [UIColor redColor] range:lrange];
}
lbl.attributedText = attrsString;
```